# How to prevent customer from replicating/duplicating my AMIs from marketplace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-marketplace

I have created an AMI that I wanted to sell on AWS marketplace. There is inbuilt authentication in AMI when booted up.
But I'm worried if the customer duplicates or replicates the AMI without authorization.
Is there any way to prevent the unauthorized duplication of AMIs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html)

> You can't copy an AMI that was obtained from the AWS Marketplace, regardless of whether you obtained it directly or it was shared with you. Instead, launch an EC2 instance using the AWS Marketplace AMI and then create an AMI from the instance.

Therefore the only way for someone to launch another instance is to launch another via the AWS Marketplace.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the reply. Your reply was really helpful. But I was wondering if there is nay way I can totally prevent unauthorized duplication.

Comment: There's always the chance that people move files etc across, if you're running an application on your host what most people will do is to register an API when the marketplace instance boots up, and forbid it being used by more than one host at the same time via a remote API.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no technical way to prevent unauthorized duplication of the content of a marketplace AMI.

> Buyers have OS-level administration access to the AMI
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/aws-marketplace-listing-checklist.html

This is a requirement of the AWS Marketplace.  The files on your AMI are trivially accessible.

Protection against unauthorized duplication and usage is a licensing restriction, not a technical one.